# Why are two Past Participles used together?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

- The pair **were pictured locked** in an embrace in an empty Luzhniki Stadium after proud Three Lions supporters filtered out of the ground.
- Homes **are seen caught** in the deluge of flooding east of Fall City, Washington.

As an English learner, I don't understand these sentences.

Can I change the sentences like :

- The pair **(who were) locked** in an embrace in an empty Luzhniki Stadium **were pictured** after proud Three Lions supporters filtered out of the ground.
- Homes **(which are) caught** in the deluge of flooding east of Fall City, Washington **are seen**.

Comment: Could you explain why? and which one is natural for native speakers?

Comment: Both of your examples I would, as a native speaker, use myself. Others are 'his criminal conviction was _viewed spent_' 'his debt was _assessed cleared_'  ' the deceased artist's painting was _preserved unfinished_'.

Comment: Can I use it in speaking and academic writing?  Is it only used in writing?

Comment: If it's English (and I would say it definitely is, myself) you can use it anywhere and anyhow.

Comment: Of particular interest is my last example _the deceased artist's painting was preserved unfinished_ wherein the sentence stands even if either one of the participles is removed.

Comment: So there is no difference if, for example, I say that                                             
 the deceased artist's painting was preserved unfinished        /                 
 the deceased artist's painting which is?was? unfinished was preserved        /     
 the deceased artist's painting unfinished was preserved.

Comment: I think it is more natural to place subject and verb closer together: *Homes are seen*. I think that the sentences are not entirely the same: *Homes caught in the deluge of the flooding are seen* refers to **specific** homes that are seen, only the ones that have been caught are seen, while the other sentence, *homes are seen caught*, has more of a sense that some homes were caught and others were not.

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't. Your first two examples are fine and perfectly natural. "Locked in an embrace" and "caught in the deluge ..." are AdjPs as  predicative (depictive) adjuncts. They are part of the VPs, hence adjuncts, but they refer to "the pair" / "homes", hence predicative.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences might make more sense with the use of commas. (Although not required, their addition is a stylistic choice.)

Let's look at a simplified version of the first example:

> The pair were pictured, locked in an embrace.

Breaking this down, it could be rephrased as follows:

> The pair were pictured. In the picture, they were locked in an embrace.

Answer (score 0):

The second "past participle" is not used as a verb, it is use *attributively* to describe *the pair* resp. *homes*.

Attributive use of participles is common:

> I like to stray off the *beaten* track.
>   I don't like rotten apples.

It may help to clear up the sentences if you imagine them in an active voice:

> The artist pictured the pair locked in an embrace in an empty Luzhniki Stadium after proud Three Lions supporters filtered out of the ground.
>   Here we see homes caught in the deluge of flooding east of Fall City, Washington.

Comment: The attributive examples you give are both of participles used adjectively ('beaten' and 'rotten') against nouns ('track' and 'apples'). I do not see how this applies to the double participles of the question (which is an interesting one) - 'pictured locked' and 'seen caught'. –

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding sources.

Answer (score 0):

The first verb is used passively in both your sentences. For the sake of understanding it might help to look at active versions of the sentences.

Someone pictured the pair **locked in an embrace**.

They saw homes **caught in the deluge of flooding**.

'Locked in an embrace' and 'caught in the deluge of flooding' are participle phrases that modify the nouns 'the pair' and 'homes' respectively.

> [Participle
>   Phrases](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/phrases.htm#participial)
>
>   Present participles, verbals ending in -ing, and past participles,
>   verbals that end in -ed (for regular verbs) or other forms (for
>   irregular verbs), are combined with complements and modifiers and
>   become part of important phrasal structures. Participial phrases
>   always act as adjectives.

This function doesn't change when the sentence becomes passive.